# Python sockets + select

Tags: python

i use this function to run my Server via Sockets:

```
def run(self):
    # The 'main' function
    print 'Running ... '
    Running = True
    while Running:
        InList,OutList,ExceptList = select.select(self.Connections,[],[])
        for Connection in InList:
            if Connection == self.Server:
                # Server got a new connecting Client
                User, Adress = self.Server.accept() # New User Connection
                Data = {'User':User,'Adress':Adress}
                self.Connections.append(Data) # Store the new User Connection
                print 'User ', Data, ' connected'
            else:
                # Some other Socket got data for the Server
                Data = Connection.recv(1024)
                if not Data:
                    print 'No new Data!'
                    break

                print Data
```

However when sending data i am getting this Error: TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method, on line 23 which is the select() line.

Looking up the manual and those examples (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/531824-chat-server-client-using-selectselect/ and http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/select/echoserver.html) i see no difference and dont understand why i wouldn't work. self.Connections contains only the Server socket and when using print self.Connections it gives me:

```
[<socket._socketobject object at 0x020B6BC8>]
```

stating, that it's a list i am passing to select() which should be correct.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just a tip - A Python convention is that variables are lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time `select.select` runs, there's no problem, because `self.Connections` contains only a socket object, which is perfectly valid.

In the second trip through the `while` loop, however, `self.Connections` has picked up another element: the `Data` dictionary constructed in the `if Connection == self.Server:` block. That dictionary is not an integer, and it doesn't have a `fileno` method, so `select.select` complains when it sees it.